# Disabled specific dates in material design DatePicker Java Android

Tags: java, android

I use Material design to implement Date Picker but I need to disabled the user select some specific dates how I can implement this ?

**Below is my code:**

```
    button=findViewById(R.id.select_date);
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    calendar.clear();
    long today=MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds();
    CalendarConstraints.Builder cons=new CalendarConstraints.Builder();
    cons.setValidator(DateValidatorPointForward.now());
    MaterialDatePicker.Builder builder=MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
    builder.setTitleText("Select booking date");
    builder.setSelection(today);
    builder.setCalendarConstraints(cons.build());
    MaterialDatePicker materialDatePicker=builder.build();
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            materialDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"Date Picker");
        }});
    materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPositiveButtonClick(Object selection) {
            System.out.println(materialDatePicker.getHeaderText());
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The values in this Calendar[] are explicitly disabled (not selectable). This option can be used together with setSelectableDays(Calendar[] days): in case there is a clash setDisabledDays(Calendar[] days) will take precedence over setSelectableDays(Calendar[] days)


String[] holidays = {"07-03-2018","05-03-2018","10-03-2018"};

    java.util.Date date = null;

    for (int i = 0;i < holidays.length; i++) {

        try {
            date = sdf.parse(holidays[i]);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        calendar = dateToCalendar(date);
        System.out.println(calendar.getTime());

        List<Calendar> dates = new ArrayList<>();
        dates.add(calendar);
        Calendar[] disabledDays1 = dates.toArray(new Calendar[dates.size()]);
        dpd.setDisabledDays(disabledDays1);
    }

 private Calendar dateToCalendar(Date date) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        return calendar;
    }
```